# Sort a List with String Indexes in R

Tags: arrays, r, string, list, sorting

I have this list **afinn_score_retweeted**. Its values when displayed in the console is below:

```
$`0`
[1] 4486797
$`2`
[1] 19538
$`-2`
[1] 30731
$`7`
[1] 1300
$`1`
[1] 3952
$`5`
[1] 37232
$`3`
[1] 153
$`-4`
[1] 156
$`-1`
[1] 5165
$`-7`
[1] 0
$`-3`
[1] 1982
$`12`
[1] 1467
$`6`
[1] 37
$`4`
[1] 291
```

I want to sort the string indexes from small values to large values and the output shall be like below:

```
$`-7`
[1] 0
$`-4`
[1] 156
$`-3`
[1] 1982
$`-2`
[1] 30731
$`-1`
[1] 5165
$`0`
[1] 4486797
$`1`
[1] 3952
$`2`
[1] 19538
$`3`
[1] 153
$`4`
[1] 291
$`5`
[1] 37232
$`6`
[1] 37
$`7`
[1] 1300
$`12`
[1] 1467
```

How am I gonna do this in R? Any help would be very much appreciated. I tried sort function with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be pretty simple. You should use `[` operator. If your list is `ll`:

```
ll[as.character(sort(as.numeric(names(ll))))]

# $`-7`
# [1] 200
# 
# $`-1`
# [1] 200
# 
# $`0`
# [1] 100
# 
# $`10`
# [1] 20
# 
# $`50`
# [1] 200
# 
# $`100`
# [1] 30
```

**Data:**

```
ll <- list("0" = 100, "-7" = 200, "100" = 30, "-1" = 200, "10" = 20, "50" = 200)

ll
# $`0`
# [1] 100
# 
# $`-7`
# [1] 200
# 
# $`100`
# [1] 30
# 
# $`-1`
# [1] 200
# 
# $`10`
# [1] 20
# 
# $`50`
# [1] 200
```

Comment: Thanks to you MKR.